# How to connect Dockerized ASP.NET Core app ->Dockerized PostgreSQL?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have 2 Dockers:
my ASP.NET Core Web server   -p 5001:80
postgresql -p 5451:5432
When I configure my Web Server to work with postgresql running on my host it works.
But when I run  configure myWeb App to work with postgresql in Docker , run  http://localhost:5001 it

```
starts but then an error appears:

    warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
          Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
          An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
    System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
     ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
     ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5451
```

If I connect the app to an external non-dockerized PostgreSQL - it works fine.

What is incorrect  and how to fix it?

There is my docker-compose file

https://pastebin.com/b8FbHSLL

Comment: How are you running the containers? `docker-compose` or `docker run`? Please add the commands you use to run the containers

Comment: you should use container port `5432` instead of `5451` publish port using docker-compose network

Comment: @ChristianFosli  I run postgres docker in the docker-compse: it contains postgresl, elastic, kibana.  My web app I run : >docker run -it --rm -p5901:5901 pman . Also, I have included it to the same compose. But the app has a PG connection string : localhost. I have replace it with 0.0.0.0  0 both give the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, `localhost` here refers to the locahost of the container which runs the webserver, not *your* localhost.
Therefore you can't use `localhost` to refer to another container, without doing some networking-related things first.

There are several ways to proceed. Since you mention in the comment you're using docker-compose, I would advise the following:

With docker-compose, networking is relatively simple, if all the services that need to communicate with each other are included in the docker-compose.yml file, you run all of them with `docker-compose up`. If you haven't specified any specific network in the docker-compose file, docker-compose sets up a single network for all the included services, which makes it possible for each container to reach the other ones, by using a hostname identical to the container name.

Basically, you can then replace `localhost` with the service-name of the service you want, i.e. if postgres is called "db" in your docker-compose file, you replace `localhost:5451` with `db:5432`.

If you specify custom networks in your docker-compose file, then you have to make sure the web-server and postgres are using the same network.

If you need to run the webapp with `docker run` instead of `docker-compose up`, then you need to include a `--network` argument so that they use the same network.

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

**Edit**: Corrected port number. We now need to use the container port, not the host port, as mentioned by @Adiii in above comment.

Comment: Thnx, I see the way, ok, will test and give a feedback

Comment: I did all what you recommended but  missed something. Now I cannot call my dockerized app  as before http://localhost:5001 . Christian could you please look a my docker-compose file? If yes I can upload it

Comment: It connects but error during the connection to PG   pm_1             |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
 at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
 at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
pm_1             |    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the docker-compose file?

Comment: Also, check the logs for the postgres container to verify it starts successfully, and maybe double-check that ports and connection strings/credentials are correct.

Comment: Done, created pastebin, please check the 1st question

Comment: Based on your 1st question, I assume the web-server is called "propman"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218761/discussion-between-zedzip-and-christian-fosli).